# Grok help - dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x

I've started learning python (only a couple of days ago), and I'm stuck on this code

```
# Enter your code for "Car colours" here.
gr = 'Cars that are green: '
si = 'Cars that are silver: '
re = 'Cars that are red: '
wh = 'Cars that are white: '
bl = 'Cars that are blue: '
print(gr, si, re, wh, bl, sep = '\n')
inp = input('Car: ')
while inp:
  Car = inp.split()
  line = input('Car: ')
  print(Car)
```

I have absolutely no idea where to go from here to complete code that has to give an output as follows

```
Car: red
Car: white
Car: blue
Car: green
Car: white
Car: silver
Car: 
Cars that are green: 1
Cars that are silver: 1
Cars that are red: 1
Cars that are white: 2
Cars that are blue: 1
```

Any help would be appreciated as I'm unable to find any elsewhere. I'm doing this code for GROK.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to use dictionaries:

```
count = {}
while True:
    color = input('Car: ')
    color = color.lower()
    if not color:
        break
    count.setdefault(color, 0)
    count[color] += 1
for color, n in count.items():
    print('Cars that are %s: %s' % (color, n))
```

Comment: Thankyou very much! Far simpler than what I had in mind but did the same job! :D

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses dictionaries and is limited to the example code that has been taught in the Grok lessons leading up to the exercise.

```
car = {}
color = input("Car: ")

while color:
  if color not in car:
    car[color] = 1
  else:
    car[color] = car[color] + 1
  color = input("Car: ")
for x in car:
  print("Cars that are", x, ":", car[x])
```

Comment: Explain how your code works.   Code only answer tend to be regarded as low quality and will sometimes be deleted.